# Cannot create/delete any files/folders in two partition

Tags: partitioning, permissions

I had windows 10 with 3 partition. I formatted my window's partition for ubuntu (remove windows) but in ubuntu I can't create any file/folder in those two partitions, remained from windows (NTFS). When I checked the owner of my files in those partitions it says the owner is me. So I'm struggling to find out how can I get full access to my files and folder there?

Comment: and those partitions are mounted as read-only?

Comment: how can i check that (sorry I'm new)

Comment: enter mount command. ro - means read-only rw - means read/write

Comment: yes it says it's read only, how can I change it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the partition has been mounted read-only(ro) it won't allow writes. You'll have to remount it with write(rw) permissions to fix the problem in that case.

`mount -o remount,rw <device>`

So if the device were /dev/sdc1 for example you'd put:

`mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdc1`

On first mounting you don't need to include "remount,". Also, if you want it to mount rw at boot, check your `/etc/fstab` file and make sure the options column for that partition includes `rw` and not `ro`. An example might be:

`/dev/sdc1  /path/to/mount  ntfs-3g  defaults,rw  0  0`

Lastly, if you want to know what other mount options might be available to you, I recommend exploring the man page for ntfs-3g:

https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfs-3g

Comment: thanks it worked, but about mounting rw at boot, I can't see my partition in that file. there is only 3 partition which are my root / and /home and swap. should I add my partition manually  and if yes could you guide me on that ?

Comment: @SaeedAm Yes you can add it manually. You can use my line as a template if you'd like, just make sure to change the device to the actual device and the mount point to the actual mount point. Afterward you can test by manually unmounting the device, running a `mount -a`, and then seeing if it's mounted again. After that, when you are able, you can do a full test by rebooting.

Comment: in file I have UUID instead of `/dev/sdc1` so should I found it or it's ok to put `/dev/sdc1` for my partition.

Comment: @SaeedAm instead of `/dev/sdc1` for the first column you can put `UUID=<uuid>` Of course, make sure to replace `<uuid>` with the actual uuid.

Comment: I add this line `/dev/**  /media/saeed/*partition label*    ntfs-3g  defaults,rw  0  0` but nothing happened after checking it by `mount` still it says `ro`

Comment: @SaeedAm if you unmount the partition and then run `mount -a` does it mount it?

Comment: nothing happened, although I'm so thankful for your help. I guess I should read more about it. I will use  your reference link you put at the end of your answer. again thanks ;-)

Comment: If the `mount -a` didn't mount it, then likely the first or second column of your line isn't correct. On top of that link I gave you, I found this to be useful as well: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NTFS-3G  I'll let you peruse those to see if they show you better how to add to the `/etc/fstab`. Your welcome! :)

Comment: sorry to bother you again. but I realize that after mounting and change it to `rw` still I can't create a directory `/dev/*** on /media/saeed/*** type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)` when I try I get this: `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘mydir’: No such file or directory`