# My HDD used for backups it doesn't have the "Delete Option" and other options

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a SSD and an HDD. Yesterday, I was still using the Windows 10 that was installed in the SSD drive, then I decided to migrate to ubuntu, so in the ending of the night, I installed ubuntu(without dual boot, it was a fresh install). Now I have a problem, my HDD unit does contain files like pictures, videos, pdfs and that kind of things and now I am not able to delete files from this HDD unit... I mean, I can open the pictures, videos and pdfs normally, but I can't delete because there is no "Delete" option. And I can't use the rename files option, the "move to..." option and the "cut" option neither.

For a better understanding, you can see a screenshot of what I mean [right here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiHpI.png).

Comment: Guys, I fixed it by following the steps [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/911019/cannot-create-delete-any-files-folders-in-two-partition)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mounted the HDD with read access only. You need to unmount it and remount it with read and write access.

Comment: Am I going to lose my files if unmount the HDD and remount it with read and write access? And are you sure that is mounted with read access only? Because when I open the HDD properties and open the "permissions" tab, it says that I have access to create and delete files as you can see [here](http://i.imgur.com/wg5m2YM.png)